# Could volcanic or geothermal activity alter the ambient temperature in a cold climate?

Tags: science-based, climate, volcanoes

OK, while I'm good with basic biology/medicine, I am not as knowledgeable in the other sciences beyond smatterings here and there. I may be wording this badly but here is what I'm looking for:

I am creating a world for my D&D campaign. This planet is similar to earth in most regards, size, relationship to the sun (so far just one, but I'm not opposed to a second one.) Based on info a gathered from another post ([Can a planet with only one pole cap exist?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/46288/can-a-planet-with-only-one-pole-cap-exist)) I have placed my continents far enough away from the northern pole that it should be mostly devoid of snow, though I would assume it would still be fairly cool, if technically temperate(ish). So my current thought is that this northern continent on/around the pole will be surrounded by near perpetual fog with occasional icebergs coming through the mist adding to it being separate from the rest of the civilized world for a long time due to the dangerous nature of waters. So, what I'm asking, perhaps poorly, is if this continent has a large volcanic or geothermal presence, similar to like Yellowstone or parts of Japan, could this activity enhance the ambient temperature, even if only in small areas, where perhaps villages or towns could develop around granting them a "perpetual" warming that allows crop growing and an easier burden during the colder months?

I'm open to all suggestions as this is still very much in the developmental phase (at least for this continent). Thanks in advance for any help anyone can give.

UPDATE: OMG, thank you all so much for your feedback, It is all so helpful. To answer some questions and bring clarity as to why I looked at this particular thing and why I'm looking at the science-based answer is simple; I have ADHD and I tend to hyper-fixate and sometimes I can back myself off and other times I can't. For me I can let myself go into a book or movie or show and forget about most issues requiring suspension of disbelief (until it becomes medical, as a 13 year EMT I lose my mind watching Grey's Anatomy). So, in this case, simply, I've already worked so hard to keep the world "low-magic" I have a long term plan of the world slowly losing it's magic, in fact I use D&D because I like the idea that in the worlds current era (roughly equivalent to the late Victorian) Vancian Magic is all anyone is really capable of and, indeed, very rare. The days of mages drawing up raw power and shaping it on the fly are long gone in the worlds ancient history.

Anyway, I am truly grateful for everyone's input and if I have any specific questions I'll post them as replies to your comments. Thanks again.

Comment: High there! A quick comment. You mention 'perpetual fog'. Unfortunately fog requires very calm weather conditions to form in significant qualities as well as interaction between a cold air and warm moist air. Usually over large bodies of water. Your continent is near the arctic circle and so high winds are going to to be a more or less common phenomenon (think polar vortexes). You'd probably be better going with constant high winds, rain/sleet ice storms as the reason your settlements aren't visited often.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thoguht of that, Probably should have considering the years I spent sailing the North Atlantic lol. Would a relatively stable fog be able to hug the coastline?

Comment: I asked about a real-world example on one of the other sites in the network: [Does the geothermal activity influence the climate in Iceland?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/18699/2958)

Comment: @PPL H8ting Bear. Not a meteorologist so I don't know. Maybe in fiords or similar inlets. Start with an mild onshore wind and there's no reason why a sea mist/fog couldn't get blown/pushed into a fiord or steep bay and be trapped there until it dissipates or the wind changes.  Since it is trapped and can't go anywhere in theory it could get quite dense.

Comment: Also you don't need to rely only on geo-thermal heating as the main driver of local climate change, geography helps as well. There are plenty of examples of often quite large valleys & gorges in cold climates where shelter from the wind protects local trees and plants by raising the local temperature/reducing wind chill to the point where plants can grow in climates that would otherwise be unsuitable. An extreme example is the Qinngua Valley (look it up) but there are plenty of other examples from less severe climates to. In effect they act a bit like oasis do in deserts but on a larger scale.

Answer (score 8):

**Why do you want this to be science-based?**

The [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) answer is "no." Geothermal activity can change the ambient in a very (very) small volume of space, but not generally. This makes sense when you think about it. There is a whomping lot of air! And when you heat it, it rises, bring in more cold air below. The rising hot air cools. Consequence: it's warm standing next to a mud pot, but walk a dozen yards away and it's cold again. It's really no different from a big old bonfire... it's just a matter of scale.

Thus, you could make a *massive* geothermal region with *lots* of geysers, mud pots, hot springs, even lava! But that's more likely to cause storms than it is to make a warm climate in a cold region. You'd have to have a LOT of those things clustered in near proximity to one another. If you're thinking, "that's just a painfully hot swamp that smells a lot like sulphur that would probably eat away everything metal..." yup, that's it.

So, short answer, no, science won't let you do what you want to do.

**But why would anybody bring science into Dungeons & Dragons?**

I'll be honest with you, I played Version #1. I have a copy of the pre-Dungeon Master's Guide boxed set — the one with the incredibly low-quality dice. I even have a copy of *Chainmail* that predates that. The reason my friends and I played the game was to escape the boring doldrums of science (with one exception, we're all science majors). Maybe the world has changed. After all, thanks to *Interstellar* and *The Expanse* everybody want things to be "as real as possible," why not D&D? Doesn't make sense to me, but the younger generation often doesn't. Just wait your turn. It'll happen to you, too.

So, from my point of view, declare the entire region you want heated to be riddled with active lava tubes a dozen feet below the surface such that the region up to about twenty feet above the ground is warm. The region being large enough such that the insertion of cold air from the sides doesn't effect the interior of the region. We make heated floors today, that's what you're shooting for. *But don't explain how that came to pass or how it works to anybody.* In fact, if they insist you explain it to them, point to my old copy of *Deities & Demigods* (the cool one with the Cthulhu mythos) and say, "that's just the way it is, buckle up."

Heck, it would be a great geology for creature-infested caves.

Comment: Bringing science to D&D is the same thing as bringing your cousin Jeff, the one who never bathes and fancies himself a womanizer, to your GF's birthday party. Not only it doesn't make sense, it will foul all the fun.

Comment: lol thanks so much and normally I would agree with you, it's just not the flavor I'm going through in this world. Although it is food for thought as I do have magic playing a big part of the worlds prehistory. And as for the "younger generation" I completely understand, as I've been playing D&D since second edition and I both know and love that edition of Deities & Demigods you're speaking of. Thanks again, I will definitely give this some thought.

Answer (score 8):

Agreeing with the content of JBH's answer, I think your best bet is to have a canyon into which a river of geothermally heated water flows.

Hot and humid air would rise and condense on the walls, creating a warm and damp environment, with a climate substantially different than away from the canyon.

But again, it would be only in the canyon, not continent wide. Not necessarily bad, considering that I suspect you want to give a direction to your players, and a canyon does so.

Comment: +1 a canyon works...

Answer (score 5):

Geothermal activity will not significantly warm the local climate, as the other answers have said. They've also pretty much covered the idea that since it's DnD it could just be magic, but since you're asking this question I'll assume that's not what you're going for.

In your other question you mentioned a warm current, and I think this will probably work. The UK has very mild winters for its latitude due to an ocean current called the [gulf stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_Stream). Since your world has an isolated continent in the middle of an ocean the same thing could happen there, with one or two large warm ocean currents serving to warm the continent and keep the winters mild.

Another thing to consider is, is it really crucial for your campaign that the other hemisphere has an ice cap? If not, you could just make the whole planet warmer. Antarctica has been a rainforest in the past, so if you don't need the other pole to be frozen then a warm and fertile polar continent is entirely possible - we used to have one here on Earth.

Comment: The gulf stream is a perfect example how OP's needs could be fulfilled IRL. Sure, it won't bring that otherwise arctic island to tropical temperatures, but southern Britain has palm trees and similar that don't really survive on the mainland until you go south of the Alps.

Comment: The gulf-stream style answer would also perfectly match up with what OPs linked question's answer already proposes.

Comment: I hadn't even given thought to the gulf stream, and am familiar enough with the the UK's mild climate. That is food for thought and ultimately I may just put a different continent up there and use this instead of my original concept. Right now I have a handful of continents that are mostly formed and another handful that are still in progress, but none of them have an official spot on "the globe" as it were, so placement is still not set in stone. Thanks!